# Appengine pushtask intermittent task queue error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using the task queue in appengine with php and am having an error that occurs under the following circumstances:

1) After I use "appcfg.py update" to update the php file which calls the task queue, the code works for about a day.

2) It does not matter what post arguments are passed when calling the task, the error eventually occurs anyway.

3) If I re-run appcfg, changing anything in the PHP file (IE adding a single space at the start of the file) will cause the error to go away for another day or so.

The following code is what is being used:

```
$task = new PushTask('taskhandler.php', 
['alert_user_fillupdate' => $alert_user_fillupdate,
'alert_user_pickupupdate' => $alert_user_pickupupdate]
);
$task_name = $task->add();
```

I have also tried adding "default" as an argument to $task->add() with no change in the behavior:

```
$task = new PushTask('taskhandler.php', 
['alert_user_fillupdate' => $alert_user_fillupdate,
'alert_user_pickupupdate' => $alert_user_pickupupdate]
);
$task_name = $task->add("default");
```

Either way, the code will work for about a day, and then appengine gives the following error, which can be put off for another day by simply modifying anything in the PHP file and updating:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'google\appengine\runtime\ArgumentError' with message 'An error occurred parsing (locally or remotely) the arguments to taskqueue.BulkAdd().' in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php:74
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php(40): google\appengine\runtime\RealApiProxy->makeSyncCall('taskqueue', 'BulkAdd', Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddRequest), Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddResponse), NULL) 

#1 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/PushQueue.php(187): google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy::makeSyncCall('taskqueue', 'BulkAdd', Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddRequest), Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddResponse)) 

#2 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/PushTask.php(292): google\appengine\api\taskqueue\PushQueue->addTasks(Array) 

#3 /base/data/home/apps/*******/taskhandler.php(369): google\appengine\api in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php on line 74
```

What could be causing this error? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having a similar problem.